# Can I screw a US garden hose into any standard threaded pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, hose

Is a US garden hose connector any kind of standard pipe thread? So that it could be screwed into a normal, say, threaded iron or PVC pipe?

I've tried a couple samples of what I had on hand and though the thread may start it doesn't really want to go on.

Comment: The adapters are cheap, and many come with valves!

Answer (score 2):

**No**, a US garden hose thread is its own thing.

[This table](http://www.onestopfire.com/threads.htm) has a useful comparison:

[image]

Note that the hose thread (called "GHT" in plumbing circles) clearly does not match ANY of the other thread specifications in this table of common sizes. I circled some table entries with the closest dimensions to GHT just for emphasis.

Though it's "3/4" diameter is nearly the same as several others, the threads-per-inch are quite different.

I suppose that the designer wanted it to screw on with fewer turns, hence the low TPI count for the common 3/4 size. Maybe this makes manufacturing tolerances easier also.

So the only way to make a screwed-together attachment is to use an appropriate spigot, bibb, or adapter.

Comment: Although I agree the main reason a standard pipe fitting 3/4" inch would leak is because there is no real seal area for the o ring or hose seal. I have done it with success but I have threading equipment and can make lots of "stuff" work on my farm but will fix it properly asap.+